# Return type as table not working with Oracle function

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle19c

I have following package and function structure , need to understand if it is possible.

If yes - then please help me understand - where I am going wrong.

Package -->

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MY_PACKAGE AS

    TYPE MY_EVENTS IS TABLE OF MY_TABLE%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER  ;
    FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION RETURN MY_EVENTS;

END MY_PACKAGE ;
```

Package body -->

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MY_PACKAGE    AS

FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION  RETURN   MY_EVENTS  IS

EVENT_RECORDS MY_EVENTS;


BEGIN

select MT.* BULK COLLECT INTO EVENT_RECORDS from MY_TABLE MT ;

/*
some processing  on EVENT_RECORDS 
*/


  RETURN EVENT_RECORDS ;


END MY_FUNCTION;
END MY_PACKAGE ;
```

The way I am trying to call this function  -->

```
select MY_PACKAGE.MY_FUNCTION from dual ;
```

It gives error -->

```
ORA-00902: invalid datatype
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 13 Column: 8
```

Thank you for your help in Advance !.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return that type at **SQL level**, then you'll have to declare it (the type) at SQL level, not within the package.

It would work the way you did it if you called `MY_FUNCTION` from PL/SQL, though.

---

Here's an example of how you might do that:

Types:

```
SQL> create or replace type t_dept_row as object
  2    (deptno number,
  3     dname  varchar2(20),
  4     loc    varchar2(20));
  5  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type t_dept_tab as table of t_dept_row;
  2  /

Type created.
```

Package:

```
SQL> create or replace package my_package as
  2    function my_function return t_dept_tab;
  3  end;
  4  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body my_package as
  2    function my_function return t_dept_tab
  3    is
  4      l_tab t_dept_tab;
  5    begin
  6      select t_dept_row(deptno, dname, loc)
  7      bulk collect into l_tab
  8      from dept;
  9
 10      return l_tab;
 11    end;
 12  end;
 13  /

Package body created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select * From table(my_package.my_function);

    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH             DALLAS
        30 SALES                CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS           BOSTON

SQL>
```

Comment: thank you for explaining , can we create a type as table of rowtype - i tried searching for examples and tried few things - but not getting it exactly

Comment: You're welcome. I added an example which shows how you might do that; have a look, please.